# Error in c# array-"does not contain definition for". Code included

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple ATM program for college. We have been taught nothing and I'm just trying to compare my program to the code of the "teacher"'s. I'm doing okay so far but getting this error: 'atmproject.custlogin' does not contain a definition for number. The code in error I have highlighted in bold and italics.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace atmproject
{
public partial class custlogin : Form
{
    public custlogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //VARIABLES
    int i = 0;
    public static int found = -1;

    private void loginexitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
        this.Close();
        form1welc.ActiveForm.Show();
    }

    // VALIDATE THE ACCOUNT EXISTS IN THE DATA ARRAY
    private void loginwithdbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < createcust.number; i++)
        {
            if (loginaccbox.Text == createcust.accountArray[i])
            {
                found = i;             //found it
                i = custlogin.***number***; // stop looping
            }
        }

        if (found == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Account does not exist");
        }
        else
        {
            // VALIDATE THE PIN IS CORRECT
            if (loginpinbox.Text != createcust.pinArray[found])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid PIN");
            }
            else
            {
                //LOAD THE CASH FORM
                withdrawselect cash = new withdrawselect();
                this.Close();
                cash.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is my teacher's code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LittleBank
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // VARIABLES
    int i = 0;
    public static int found = -1;

    private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // VALIDATE THE ACCOUNT EXISTS IN THE DATA ARRAY

        for (i = 0; i < Form2.number; i++)
        {
            if (txtAccount.Text == Form2.accountArray[i])
            {
                found = i;          // found it
                i = Form2.number;   // stop looping
            }
        }

        if (found == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Account doest not exist ");
        }
        else
        {
            // VALIDATE THE PIN IS CORRECT
            if (txtPin.Text != Form2.pinArray[found])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a Valid Pin");
            }
            else
            {
                //LOAD THE CASH FORM
                Form4 Cash = new Form4();
                this.Close();
                Cash.Show();
            }
        }

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Form1.Welcome.Show();
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtAccount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I've changed her names of forms; her Form2 is my createcust. The reason I changed txtAccount to loginaccbox is because in her code, all text boxes were named the same across forms so I named each text box as relevant to it's form to differentiate when calling (am I making sense when I say calling?)

Another thing I don't understand is why I get an error for that line but a couple of lines up, createcust.number gets no errors? It would suggest that's because createcust does have a definition for number, so I looked at the variables in that form and there was "static public string int number = 0;". I copied that over to custlogin, but the error remains. I changed it to public static, still there. Help please?

Comment: If his answer solved your problem please mark his answer as the correct answer. Just tick the check under the vote count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `custlogin` class has no member called `number`.  Notice that in the teacher's code the class in question is called `Form3`, but `number` is defined on a class called `Form2`.  Presumably, outside of the code you've shown, there's a class called `Form2` and *that* class has a member called `number`.  Specifically a `static` member called `number`.  Your code isn't referring to another class, it's referring to its own class, which doesn't have that member.

You'll need to define that other class from the teacher's example as well (not shown in the code you've posted).

Comment: That worked! I had originally written "createcust.number", following her code, but I changed it when I got an error, thinking everything had to be of the same form. Changed it back to createcust.number and error disappeared. I obviously have no idea what I'm doing, just trying to get this project finished and plan to study c# properly over the summer. Thank you for helping me!!

Comment: @Paula: Glad you're learning :)  It'll take time to get it all, a lot of seemingly simple things have much deeper and farther reaching implications.  For example, there's a *lot* I would change/fix in your teacher's code.  But addressing those issues may obscure the basics from you.  Just understand that while your teacher is showing you how to write *working* code, he/she is not necessarily showing you how to write *good* code.  Hopefully you'll get that later :)